# Setting Image Anchor properties of image using jxl

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I am trying to add a logo(png) to excel sheet. I am writing followng code for this:

```
WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Name", 1);
sheet.mergeCells(0, 0, 6, 6);
File logo = new File("/path/to/logo.png");
WritableImage im = new WritableImage(0, 0, 2, 6, logo);
sheet.addImage(im);
```

The logo gets added successfully to the sheet but the problem is that the image get stretched if I change column boundries. How can I set the Image aanchor properties so that the image does not stretch/resized when I add or change column boundries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert image to excel file using JXL without stretching it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136750/insert-image-to-excel-file-using-jxl-without-stretching-it)

Comment: similar.. but, the answerer hasn't explained the Anchor thing properly..  also, i am unable to comment there cz of lesser reputation.

Comment: I am not able to find any WritableImage.MOVE_WITH_CELLS; and WritableImage.NO_MOVE_OR_SIZE_WITH_CELLS;

Answer (score 0):

You set the static property as such:

```
WritableImage im = new WritableImage(0, 0, 2, 6, logo);
im.setImageAnchor(WritableImage.NO_MOVE_OR_SIZE_WITH_CELLS);
sheet.addImage(im);
```